# Bacpac Import fails with error 'The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation'

Tags: sql-server, restore, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I want to restore some production azure database on my local machine for development purposes. 
So I exported the production database to a `.bacpack` file & downloaded that file on local.
Now I am trying to restore that file on my local machine using [sqlpackage utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx#Import%20Parameters%20and%20Properties) but it is throwing following error

> *** Error importing database:An error occurred during deployment plan
>   generation. Deployment cannot continue. The Element or Annotation
>   class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class
>   CatalogCollation.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what does this error means & how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's especially important to stay current with updates when using Azure SQL Database. Make sure you have the latest version of SSDT for VS 2017 installed, which is 15.7.3 as of this writing. From the VS 2017 menu, Help-->Check for Updates.

Comment: It seems you may need to update Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework on your computer. Please download the latest version here. After installation, you will find it on the following path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe” and updates independently of SSDT / SSMS.

Comment: Latest version is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100297

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed as part of build 14.0.17230.0 (not 14.0.17320.0) of SSMS.
Please update to the latest version.

You can read more about here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/02/15/what-will-happen-with-catalog_collation-and-case-sensitive-vs-case-insensitive/

Answer (score 3):

Install a later version of the Data Tier Application framework eg

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55088

That way you don't necessarily have to do a full upgrade, just use this standalone version..

An example import command would be:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Import /tdn:NEWDBNAME /tp:SQLSERVERUSERPASSWORD /tsn:SQLSERVERINSTANCE /tu:SQLSERVERUSERPASSWORD /sf:"C:\Temp\BACPACFILENAME.bacpac"

Comment: "/tu" should be the SQL Server user to use to access the target database.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#import-parameters-and-properties

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade/install anything.

Just copy .bacpac file to your Azure storage and try Import Database option available in Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).